# count how many times each number occurs

Tags: awk, sed, grep, numeric-data

A file contains 5 columns with numbers

Example:

```
12 34 67 88 10
 4 90 12 10 7
33 12 5  76 34
```

I would like to print the same number and see how many times it goes out.
Example:

```
3 : 12
2 : 34
```

Comment: presumably only for numbers that occur more than once?

Comment: @Kusalananda it's `count : value`.

Comment: Are you asking about finding and counting *duplicates*?  Is that what you mean by "print the same number"?  That's very unclear because you don't say what it has to be the same as.

Comment: I suppose you want the count of how many times each number appears, so edited the title to actually say that.

Answer (score 11):

This `awk` script prints output as in your example:

```
awk '{ 
         for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) # loop over all fields/columns
            dict[$i]++;      # count occurrence in an array using the field value as index/key
     }
 END {                           # after processing all data
         for (key in dict)       # iterate over all array keys
             if(dict[key]>1)     # if the key occurred more than once
                 print dict[key] " : " key    # print counter and key
     }' inputfile
```

With the example input, the output is

```
2 : 10
3 : 12
2 : 34
```

If you remove the condition `if(a[i]>1)` it will also list numbers that occurred only once.

If you want to sort the result in descending order of the number of occurrence, append

```
| sort -nr
```

which means sort in reverse numerical order.

So the `awk` command shown above combined with sort

```
awk '...' inputfile | sort -nr
```

produces

```
3 : 12
2 : 34
2 : 10
```

As mentioned in glenn jackman's comment you can instruct GNU AWK to sort the array values when processing with `for` by adding `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"` on top of the `END` block.

```
 END {                           # after processing all data
         # In GNU AWK only you can use the next line to sort the array for processing
         PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc" # sort descending by numeric value
         for (key in dict)       # iterate over all array keys
             if(dict[key]>1)     # if the key occurred more than once
                 print dict[key] " : " key    # print counter and key
     }
```

With this GNU specific extension you get sorted results without piping to `sort`.

Comment: If you're using GNU awk, you could put `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"` at the top of the END block to sort the output: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

Answer (score 9):

You could use a pipeline

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < datafile | sort | uniq -c -d
```

Depending on how refined you want your answer you could filter for numeric values. Remove the `-d` to see all values, not just where the count is more than one.

Comment: You could append `| awk '($1 > 1) && ($2 > 0) { print $1 " : " $2 }'` to get output similar to the example in the question.

Comment: This is OK but print not in order increase

Comment: @InsideMiamiTattoo where in your question did you say anything about a sorted output? Do you want to sort by count or by value?

Comment: @Bodo agreed, but if I did that I would have addressed the entire request with `awk` rather than as a pipeline.

Comment: maybe use `tr -s` to avoid blank lines due to multiple spaces.

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to [@roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502347/22222), but the `sed` lets us avoid having multiple spaces in the output when counting:

```
$ sed -E 's/ +/\n/g' file | sort | uniq -c -d
      2 10
      3 12
      2 34
```

And, to sort numerically and add the `:`, you can do:

```
$ sed -E 's/ +/\n/g' file | sort | uniq -c -d | 
    sort -rn | sed -E 's/([0-9]) /\1 : /'
      3 : 12
      2 : 34
      2 : 10
```

Alternatively:

```
$ grep -oP '\d+' file | sort | uniq -c -d | 
    sort -rn | sed -E 's/([0-9]) /\1 : /'
      3 : 12
      2 : 34
      2 : 10
```

Or, with `perl`:

```
$ perl -lae '$k{$_}++ for @F; 
              END{ 
                @keys = grep { $k{$_} > 1 } keys(%k);  
                @keys = sort { $k{$b} <=> $k{$a} } @keys;

                print "$k{$_} : $_" for @keys
              }' file
3 : 12
2 : 10
2 : 34
```

Or, if you're into the whole brevity thing:

```
$ perl -lae '$k{$_}++for@F}{print"$k{$_} : $_"for sort{$k{$b}<=>$k{$a}}grep{$k{$_}>1}keys(%k)' file 
3 : 12
2 : 10
2 : 34
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input file is named `bar` and is structured as nicely as you illustrate (whitespace and/or newlines between the numbers), one solution might be:

```
for n in $(cat bar); do echo "$n"; done | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 0):

command:

```
sed "N;s/\n/ /g" filename | sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| perl -pne "s/ /\n/g"| sed '/^$/d'| awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print x,a[x]}}'|awk '$2 >1 {print $0}'
```

output

```
sed "N;s/\n/ /g" i.txt | sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| perl -pne "s/ /\n/g"| sed '/^$/d'| awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print x,a[x]}}'|awk '$2 >1 {print $0}'

10 2
12 3
34 2
```

Answer (score -3):

ok im resolved :

```
awk '($1 > 1) && ($2 > 0) { print $1 " : " $2 }' xxx.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Thanks All

Comment: That doesn't seem to address your requirement at all. Have you tested it?